# Is there a similar class in c++ like the Desktop class in java? (Windows specific)

Tags: java, c++

Given the following code:

```
    import java.awt.Desktop;
    import java.io.IOException;
    public class MyClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
     try{
       Desktop.getDesktop.open("file.txt");
     catch(IOException e){
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
   }
 }
```

I would like to know if there is a similar class in c++ that performs the same function as the statement  `Desktop.getDesktop.open("file.txt");`?

If so please describe how to use it with method calls to open a file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ShellExecute(0, 0, "file.txt", 0, 0 , SW_SHOW );
```

Comment: Could you put this in a main method in c++ syntax .

Comment: You should mention that this is a Windows-specific question. Edit : OP added it to the question, so nevermind.

Comment: @Don You don't even know how to make a c++ main method?

Comment: Have used c++ before but a very long time ago and for less than a month.

Comment: If it is anything like C, I think the main method looks like: int main(){ ..code here..} Not sure why ppl love to try to make others feel bad, guess it is a SO thing.